# RHEL6: Selinux not logging AVC denial messages

Tags: redhat, selinux

I'm trying to configure a set of lockdown rules. My approach is to start with a restricted user, and use `audit2allow` messages to selective add permissions. My problem is that I don't see the expected denial messages in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

For my test, I'm logged in to the box via SSH as a restricted user. I try to cat `/etc/init.d/sshd`. With SELinux enforcing, I see a "permission denied" error in the shell. With SELinux in permissive mode, I can run cat without an issue. But in either case, I don't see denial messages in the log.

Update: I do see denied messages when trying to `mount` a partition, but still not for `cat`.

Comment: Have you ensured the `auditd` daemon is running and there's a rule in place to log the restricted action?

Comment: Check auditd is running, if not look in /var/log/messages

Comment: auditd is running: ps aux | grep auditd
root      1829  0.0  0.0  27636   816 ?        S<sl 09:25   0:00 auditd

Comment: @dawud: I didn't think I needed an explicit log rule. I thought SELinux denial are logged by default.

Comment: They are logged by default. Please post the results of your support case with Red Hat that you opened prior to asking.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the default selinux policy has some don't audit rules, which were catching this case. Once I disabled don't audit, I see the expected behavior.

```
semodule --disable_dontaudit --build
```

Comment: Genius!, in my case selinux was not showing violations from tclass unix_dgram_socket

Answer (score 4):

Try `ausearch -ts today -m avc -m user_avc -m selinux_err` and see what comes up.

You are possibly running into a constraint violation or an invalid context generation. `selinux_err` will pick those up.

Also *some* messages (in particular userspace object managers) may only log into dmesg. So try looking there too.

Answer (score 0):

Edge case - if you `rm /var/log/audit/audit.log`, auditd is not smart enough to create a new file. If you `touch /var/log/audit/audit.log`, auditd is not smart enough to write to the new file you just created. You have to restart the auditd service to get your logging working again.